# Reasons why adding static to all the functions in a translation unit may increase the size of the resulting object file?

Tags: c++, c, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

My intention is to limit the visibility of a number of symbols to the translation unit where they are defined. [This commit](https://github.com/fmeerkoetter/sensors-software/commit/1e8c49f36d8ceb80652cc3f6bdf5852ce707bea4) is adding 688 bytes to the resulting firmware file. Any ideas why?

The compiler involved is a GCC 4.8.2
The target device is an ESP-8266 microcontroller.
The optimizer is set to -Os.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps after adding `static` the functions are now inlined by the compiler, while before they were not? A function does not have to be explicitly marked with `inline` to be inlined.

Comment: In my opinion, it is good practice to do as you are doing (make all functions not used outside their TU `static`) — you can routinely see it in the C code I post on SO, though I don't usually comment on it. So, good job on doing that. If, as seems plausible, inlining causes the growth and that is a problem for you, you may need to investigate 'optimizing for space' instead of 'optimizing for speed'.  (GCC 8.2.0 documentation on [Optimizing options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options). You'll need the equivalent for 4.8.2 — easy to deduce.)

Comment: What optimization levels are you using? Does this happen with `-Os` optimisation? Probably one function is inlined twice or more, thus you will get bigger resulting firmare. Can you check what if you mark all those functions with `__attribute__((__noinline__))`?

Comment: Try compiling with `-Os` ?

Comment: Updated the question with the optimization level used.

Comment: Generate the assembly for both versions. Compare.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for your suggestion. I sprinkled __attribute__((noinline__)) over that commit but very much to my surprise it only changes the size of the firmware by a few bytes (20 something).